# Flash Actionscript 3 sliding text in text box

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, text, scroll

I've perused around Adobe's pages and the internet but there seems to be no solid way of finding out how to make text slide in a text box.

What I am trying to do is try to do is that if a line of text is longer than the text box size, then it will slide automatically to the end of that string. If that made no sense, I am trying to get the text to slide like it does on an iPod, iPhone, or iTunes: if the album title is longer than there is room, it will scroll *automatically* so the rest of the album title is readable.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a "Text ticker" effect - which is basically masking a textfield and animating that field along the x-axis. Here is an example with source: http://scottrockers.com/blog/resources/tutorials/flash-ticker-scrolling-text-in-actionscript-3-0